# Node js setup an Anchor

Tags: javascript, node.js, anchor

anybody know how to handle an anchor like this?
i redirect from another page to the page with these anchor items

http://example.com/page-name#9009bac1153753cf6741eda10bc03121-ZJJNkHQ2-95.26336735469833-1661

i want to set 
 1 - 9009bac1153753cf6741eda10bc03121
 2 - ZJJNkHQ2
 3 - 95.26336735469833
 4 - 1661

and get these values on the page to set them automatically in input boxes.

Comment: Use a query string if you want to access the data on the server.

Comment: i want these anchor send by server but handle completly on client side

Comment: If you're asking about client side code, then tagging this `node.js` was pretty misleading. You're question is a bit broad. What are you asking about? Reading the URL? Extracting the fragment ID from it? Finding inputs in the DOM? Setting their values? Those are all really trivial things that you should be able to find hundreds of guides to on Google, but put together you're asking for quite a lot of different things.